# pyconfig.h missing during "pip install cryptography"

Tags: python, cryptography, centos, scrapy, pip

I wanna set up scrapy cluster follow this link [scrapy-cluster](http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/introduction/quickstart.html#cluster-quickstart),Everything is ok before I run this command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The requirements.txt looks like:

```
cffi==1.2.1
characteristic==14.3.0
ConcurrentLogHandler>=0.9.1
cryptography==0.9.1
...
```

I guess the above command means to install packages in requirements.txt.But I don't want it to specify the version,So I change it to this:

```
cat requirements.txt | while read line; do pip install ${line%%[>=]*} --user;done
```

When install cryptography,it gives me the error:

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:12:24:fatal error:pyconfig.h:No such file or directory 
#include <pyconfig.h>
```

I don't know how to solved this , I have tried a lot of methods ,but failed. my system is centos 7, and the version of python is 2.7.5(default).
Besides, Is there any other scrapy frame which is appliable for a large number of urls . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 38):

For Ubuntu, python2

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

For Ubuntu, python3

```
apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: `apt-get install python3.6-dev` did it for me.

Answer (score 19):

I have solved it by myself. for the default python of centos, there is only a file named pyconfg-64.h in usr/include/python2.7/,So run the command

```
yum install python-devel
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 12):

for python3.6,

`apt-get install python3.6-dev`

and

`apt-get install libssl-dev libffi-dev`

Comment: apt-get install libssl-dev libffi-dev help me

Answer (score 1):

i use python 2 on ubuntu and got the same problem when installing cryptography.
after i run this command

```
apt-get install python-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev
```

then it works.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.7 on Debian, the following works for me.

```
apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

and

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

You may also need:

```
apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Debian based distro (AntiX distro), together with `apt-get install python3-dev`, I also installed `rust`, to complete successfully the `pip3 install cryptography` command. So, I gave:

```sh
    $ sudo apt-get install build-essential curl python3-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev
    $ sudo curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

[image: (Figure 1) | Rust installation]

When prompted (Figure 1), type 1 and hit Enter on your keyboard.
Once it completes, you have to give following commands:

```sh
    $ source $HOME/.cargo/env
    $ source ~/.profile
    $ pip3 install cryptography
```