# What does Failed building wheel for cryptography for Pyopenssl in DigitalOcean means?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I was trying to install pyopenssl module in Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 server. I am getting this error Failed building wheel for cryptography at the end followed by some errors.

```
Collecting pyopenssl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/de/f8342b68fa9e981d348039954657bdf681b2ab93de27443be51865ffa310/pyOpenSSL-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=2.8 (from pyopenssl)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/60/da377e1bed002716fb2d5d1d1cab720f298cb33ecff7bf7adea72788e4e4/cryptography-2.8.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cryptography>=2.8->pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.8->pyopenssl)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vxubdrh0/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp7omz3s7mpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cryptography
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/ocsp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cryptography/x509   
  running egg_info
  writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.azure-pipelines'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.azure-pipelines'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.travis'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'rtd-requirements.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_padding.c'
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_constant_time.c'
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_openssl.c'
  building '_openssl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_openssl.o -Wconversion -Wno-error=sign-conversion
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_openssl.c:22:24: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: cryptography, pyopenssl
  Found existing installation: cryptography 1.2.3
    Not uninstalling cryptography at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
  Running setup.py install for cryptography: started
    Running setup.py install for cryptography: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vxubdrh0/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cb9nh_qa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cryptography
    running egg_info
    writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.azure-pipelines'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.travis'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'rtd-requirements.txt'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_openssl.o -Wconversion -Wno-error=sign-conversion
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_openssl.c:22:24: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
```

This problem was also coming while doing `pip3 install cryptography` and but it went away when I added all dependencies with this command -

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev
```

What I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manged to figure out myself somehow.

`apt-get install python3.6-dev` did it for me.

Although I did `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`, the problem had persisted for some reason.

Thanks to Hatshepsut's comment in [pyconfig.h missing during "pip install cryptography"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038134/pyconfig-h-missing-during-pip-install-cryptography)